# "You are paid to answer my questions!" - how to handle silly questions?

Tags: teaching, teaching-assistant, answering-questions

How do I handle silly questions? By silly, I mean questions that are unrelated to the material of the course.

First, I am a [TA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant). Recently, a student asked me a very silly question at the end of a lab session. I say silly because:

1. it was not related to the lecture,
2. it was asked at the end of a lecture - and the classroom was already full with the students of the next class, and
3. I have previously talked about this issue.

The student insisted that I answer his question many times. So, I told him: "*It is already late, but let me know about your question*" .. when he asked it, I told him: "*You can't be serious, this is not a question!*"

He got upset, and he told me: "*You are paid to answer my questions!*"

I got angry, but how should I handle similar situations?

"I have previously talked about this issue." -- Yes, I talked about this issue even though it is not part of the course and the lecture. I talked about it to add more applications to the course material.

Comment: If you can answer the question then what @waiwai933 said, if not then: "I'm sorry, I can't answer that question because it is not my field of expertise. Any question related with our course? No? See you next day :)"

Comment: Also: No question is silly to the person who's asking it. It *is* part of your responsibility as a TA to help folks who are having trouble with a concept, whether you've gone over it before or not. If they really aren't getting it after repeated tries and you can't think of another way to help them, refer them to the professor's office hours and let them try at that level... but the TA's job is specifically to offload most of that work from the professor.

Comment: "No, I am paid to answer questions _about the course material_, during lab sessions and during my posted office hours.  If you have a question about the course material, please bring it to my office hours.  Now if you'll please excuse me, another class needs to use the room, and I have another appointment."

Comment: Also you could include some information about the country of the college/student/you. It would help us assess it more thoroughly.

Comment: @JeffGohlke .. no students don't pay me. University pays me. Students debt is not my issue.

Comment: RE: _Students don't pay me. University pays me._ Hmmm... and where does the university get its money from?

Comment: @J.R. Primarily alumni, actually. Although my particular salary (like all academic personnel) is paid by the state.

Comment: @JeffE - Whether the students pay me directly or not, I feel like I am accountable to them at some level. That doesn't hurt me one bit.

Comment: @J.R. Maybe not *accountable* to them, but *responsible for* them, certainly.  An instructor's job is to communicate knowledge.  If the claim is that "Because I am not paid with the students' money, I have no responsibility towards them," that should be easy to demonstrate the absurdity of with a different example.  Suppose you are a contractor for a software company.  It essentially boils down to "I'm paid by a third party."  But being paid by a third party doesn't change the fact that it (the students' knowledge or the software, respectively) are your *product*, that you *own*.

Comment: @Ajed : it sounds like the student is treating you with disrepect, which is unacceptable.  You shouldn't have to tolerate such abuse.  Don't let your students walk all over you, or they will.  Just tell him you can't answer the question right now, ask him to come to your office, and try to be not to be rude so you don't get in trouble.

Comment: @J.R. Of course, me too.  But it's an _ethical_ obligation, not a _financial_ one.  I'm not accountable to my students because they pay me; I'm accountable to the students because they _trust_ me.

Comment: Why would you have done 3) previously talk about it when 1)  is not related to the lecture is true??

Comment: @Spork .. because I like giving my students extra information. Real applications to what they study. things to make their course more interesting. things to help them in the job market!

Comment: **NB**: I've cleaned up many comments, which side-tracked from the original question. I have probably deleted useful content in the process, but it was impossible to maintain a consistent state. Please remember that comments are not meant to be persistent, and that any meaningful conversation should be done in the chat.

Comment: @Ajed - Is the question inappropriate beyond being silly?  What about the question makes you angry?

Comment: I think you should start by apologizing to the student. You are not paid to answer *every* question, but you should have been able to handle the situation more professionally. You should have not let it get to you on a personal level.

Comment: @kikito, I agree with you. In fact, I will apologize and answer his question.

Comment: "Well, yes I am, but not very much."

Comment: Why to get angry?!

Comment: I down-voted this question because you did not tell us what the question was or why it was silly. Just because it's been covered already - doesn't make it silly. It means that you've failed to educate this person and he needs more help understanding something.

Comment: Remember, there are no stupid questions, just stupid students.  jk

Comment: The TA already talked about what the student ask. So actually he already answered it. Clearly the student didnt pay attention or came late to the class. Won't you all get sick of being asked something you've already explained before??

Answer (score 178, accepted):

> I got angry, but. . how should I handle similar situations?

Got angry? No good!

You're not necessarily paid to answer his question but you are paid to help advance knowledge and learning.

Unfortunately, the tone of your answer doesn't let us know exactly how "silly" the question was (was it silly because it was personal question that had no bearing on the course? Was it silly because it was not relevant to the course material but possibly relevant to the overall subject? Was it silly because you had already covered the material in class? Was it silly because he was asking at the end of the lab session?) so unfortunately the exact way in which to respond might vary, but you might try:

1. If it's a matter of time and you can't answer it because you have to clear the room, tell him, "Give me a few minutes to pack up my things to get out of the classroom." Clear the room, entertain question.
2. If it's a matter of you having another appointment, then get him to submit the question over email or in writing or before next class.
3. If it's silly because it's not related to the lecture, I usually do my best to entertain these kinds of questions because it sometimes means the student is interested in other topics around the material. If my class is on object-oriented design and programming in Java, but the student asks me about "how can you use design in procedural programming languages like C?" I'd probably give some ideas on how it could apply to that situation.
4. If it's a personal question that you don't want to answer, you can say, "I don't feel comfortable answering that", "It's none of your business", "I can't talk about this", or similar.
5. If it's a stupid question because it's sooooo obvious or because you covered it before, then, sorry, it's not a silly question but is something the student needs explanations for. Get him to visit you over office hours for extra help.
6. If it's a matter of the student talking on and wasting time with questions, then you can ask the student politely to keep questions for after the class. If the student is trolling you with questions and is otherwise being a nuisance this option usually works as well.

Yes, it is rude for him to declare "You are paid to answer my questions!" but it's also rude to say that "Your question is silly". You are the teacher, the role model, the example, so you should be more patient with them than they are with you. Besides, if you tell them  you'll answer it later, you can simply say, "Just wait - I haven't answered your question *yet*."

Comment: Very wise, professional advice. Good distinctions among the possible interpretations of the words. Excellent.

Comment: I like this answer a lot, but you left out one obvious possibility. What do you do if the student is trying to troll you by asking an obviously silly question and knows that it is silly? Should the TA take option 5 nevertheless?

Comment: Nice attempt at trying to answer an unanswerable question due to having no detail.

Comment: @rumtscho If students troll, often you can laugh it off and counter it with a witty statement. If that's not the case (I for example am not a very funnyman kind of guy) then I just say, "We can talk about that one after class. Let's move on for now." (Option 6) Or, if you have the time for it, you could actually ask the other students what they think of that question and make it a discussion exercise. That depends on the question though.

Comment: @Irwin I like your answer. I would go for case 3). the only problem is that the time was over, and I asked the students to do something completely different during the lab. Imagine working extra hours to prepare a lab, you are tired, you are busy, you need to leave the lab, and go to another class, you tell the student that it is not time to ask questions many times, then after accepting to answer your question he gives you a silly question [no it is not proc. P vs. OOP - it is more like why windows use 'dir' but linux use 'ls' to list files while talkin about OOP]. What will ur answer be? :)

Comment: Actually no need to answer my last question, but I appreciate your answer the most. I think I should have been more patient with the student. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I'm tired, I'm busy, I need to leave the lab, and go to another class. What would my answer be? It would most certainly **not** be, "This is not a question!" I might say, "I can't answer you right now, but let me get back to you on that." Or, if I don't have the expertise to answer, I could say, "Sorry, I don't know the answer to that." Or even, "Some things just are what they are, and no one really knows the reason." But if a student begins with "Why..." then it most certainly **is** a question.

Comment: "I have already told you twice that I need to leave.  If you have questions about the course material, please bring them to office hours. Goodbye."

Comment: I guess the generalisation is that no matter what you should keep  your cool and act professionally. You are a professor and they are students: the situation is asymetric, there are things they could tell you that are rude but under no circumstances you should reply in the same manner.

Comment: This is a good answer because it encourages thinking in advance about how to deal with various situations. All the comments complaining about lack of details are missing the point -- the specific situation described is already over, and the OP is explicitly asking about how to handle similar situations _in the future_. The description was deliberately general so as to describe the _category_ of situation which the OP would consider "similar". This answer will encourage the OP and others to think about many more details of the situation, and how different subcategories need different responses.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice.

Answer (score 93):

> "you can't be serious, this is not a question!"

Don't say this. Regardless of the question, this makes it sound like you think the student is either (1) intentionally wasting time or (2) very stupid. You can't make progress from there.

Next, if it's a quick question that's related to the topic of the course, but not the lecture necessarily, then the best thing to do is to take a moment to answer it anyway, since (1) the student might think the two things are related and it'll clarify things if you just explain it now, and (2) it'll be much less hassle that way.

If it requires an in-depth explanation, and you don't have the time for it because you have something else to attend to, tell the student that and also find the student a solution, whether that is telling him/her (1) to email you, (2) to ask you at the next lab, or (3) to ask the lecturer during office hours.

Comment: Great answer - to add to this, don't be afraid to refuse to answer a question if it's outside of your jurisdiction. For example, if it's a question from a topic not in my course, or even another course, I'd be happy to answer it in a lab or tutorial if there is time and no one else needs help. But I won't answer it in my own time. If its a question like *"will this equation be in the exam?"*, **yes** it's a silly question, but **no** you don't tell the student that. **tl;dr:** don't be afraid to refuse to answer a question, but be diplomatic about it.

Comment: @Moriarty I feel cheated that you put the tl;dr at the end :)

Answer (score 25):

To add to waiwai's excellent response, a good model to follow for TA's and faculty alike is professionalism.  All too often, academics behave in an arrogant and demeaning manner.

How would you feel if your doctor told you "you can't be serious, this is not a question!"?  What about your lawyer?

Comment: well, if I ask a lawyer how to make a pizza, then I can expect much harsher answer .. :)

Comment: @AJed, you seem oblivious to the fact that the student might not know the question is not related. If you ask a programmer a question about excel or word, chances are he's not going to know the answers - because you might expect a programmer to know this, though it's not related whatsoever to his actual field.

Comment: A lawyer will give you respectful, professional advice that will include how to find a pizza-making expert.

Comment: @DylanMeeus As a programmer, I would hope other programmers would have enough experience with Excel or Word (or some other spreadsheet/word processing programs) to answer the sort of questions people who think programmers are well-informed on those applications would ask, and if not, know enough to research the question and obtain an answer in a short period of time (assuming the solution isn't the sort that seems simple but is actually really complex). It's not a matter of field of expertise; those are programs that are now ubiquitous and should've been used in the programmer's education.

Comment: @JAB: I agree that they should be able to look it up, but the people who ask use software like Word much more often, and should also be able to. And Word in Excel in a programmer's education? We only had HPUX and Emacs...

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Programmers generally have an education beyond just learning how to write code, though those whose school days were prior to the 90s may not have had as much early experience with such programs as those from younger generation. However, I've found that, very often, the issues people have with Excel/Word/etc. are not issues that require detailed knowledge of and early experience with the program in question to resolve. For the most part, it seems to come down to a matter of willingness to investigate and resolve the issue; for example, if you were only now exposed to emacs, ...

Comment: would you ask someone who seemed like they might know the control/escape sequences for various commands, or would you look them up and research them on your own, and most importantly, would you be willing to experiment and investigate within the program itself? From my (admittedly small compared to some) experience, reliable programmers tend to fall into the latter category, and that in itself often leads to knowing more about programs others may use more often. Of course, I still learn new things about programs I use on a daily basis now and then, but progs tend to know more than they think.

Comment: @JAB You're getting way too caught up in the specifics of being someone in IT.  The analogy Dylan made was only meant to try and explain the concept to the OP.

Comment: @JAB just like Jeff said, I only said so to draw an analogy - albeit I do think every programmer has some experience with excel even if just from highschool, so maybe the analogy wasn't 100% clear to you. 

Indeed, in computerscience and software engineering in particular, people like to do their own research and figure things out on their own - using books or the internet. But that's really a technicality to the question :p

Comment: @AJed - you mentioned in the comments on the question that you had touched on the topic previously.  This really does make it related since it is something you previously mentioned in relation to the course, even if it isn't strictly part of the course.

Comment: @vadim123 ... and charge you for it.

Answer (score 24):

First, I'll assume that the student did actually ask a very silly question.

One thing that needs to be always taken into consideration in situations such as this is: Is the student aware of the silliness of the question?

While it may be obvious to you that the question is indeed silly, it may not be obvious to the student. You haven't posted any in-depth information about the whole background of the case, but it could very well be that the student is misunderstanding something extremely fundamental. You claim that the question is not related to the lecture, but at the same time, you say that you have in fact previously talked about the issue. In student's mind, that could somehow relate the issue to the lecture.

One more thing that could be very problematic is if student has a flawed thought process. This can cause the student to relate things that are not actually related and to find cause and effect relationships where there are none.

For example, due to administrative problems at my university, we were required to take an advanced course in one field before taking an introductory course. I already had some experience in that field, so a number of my fellow students asked me questions when they had problems with that exam. Some of them were actually very silly! Often, the silliest were for me the hardest to explain since that required figuratively digging through their brain in order to find the cause of the reasoning that got them to ask me the question in the first place. It often turned out that there was a mistake in reasoning somewhere or that they misunderstood something at a very basic level. One more thing that I noticed is that some people would try to avoid fully understanding the issue. Often, after explaining A for example, I'd have conversation going something like "Is A clear?" "Yes!" "Really?" "Yes, really." "100% clear?" "Yes, crystal clear!" and then it turns out that it wasn't clear.

Just explaining the initial problem and stopping there in cases such as the one I mentioned in the previous paragraph is just treating the symptoms of a disease and not the cause itself.

Another thing I'd like to mention is that (at least in my environment) those who ask questions do actually care about the subject they're learning and in general have a valid problem. It's usually those who don't ask questions that have no idea what's going on.

Next, I'll write a bit about "You're paid" problem itself.
It's commonly repeated that there are no bad questions, only bad answers. In my opinion, whoever produced that piece of wisdom didn't see enough questions.

You need to make a policy explaining what you should do in cases of inappropriate questions. Are you or are you not payed (or for some other reason expected) to answer such questions? What should you do in case you get a student who's too stupid to pass the course you're TA-ing for? What about students who can't form an answerable question in their mind? What about students who ask malicious questions? I was quite surprised to hear from one student at my school that he asks a certain TA senseless questions just because he like to see her struggle to answer them.

Only thing I can advise here is to think hard about what you are and are not expected to do. Talk to your colleagues about that and talk to your superiors about that. Make the limits clear to yourself and  to your students. This way, when you come to a similar situation again and you explore all other options, you can honestly and with clear consciousness respond to "You are paid to answer my questions!" with "No, I'm not!"

Finally, I'd like to recommend to you to keep the tension low if at all possible. In this particular case, you mentioned that the student insisted that you answer the question many times. That probably means that the question is important to him. Is it normal that students should ask you more than once to answer a question? Is that expected in your culture? I never had to ask a professor or a TA question more than once in during my whole education so far. You provided an answer that upset the student. Were you aware that the student would be upset by such answer?  If you were, think about why you gave that answer. Was that student confrontational before? Does he ask too many questions? Were you having a bad day? Did you give such an answer just because the student asked at an inappropriate time?

Answer (score 24):

I don't care how smart you are or how much of a rockstar you are in your field.  You can be the most brilliant physicist on the planet, but you shouldn't be teaching PHYS 1101 if you can't convey basic information in a professional way to an *uneducated* audience.  I emphasize "uneducated", because that's what your audience is.  They don't know anything.  It's your job to turn someone who knows *nothing* into someone who knows *something*.  That's what being a professor is about (and, by extension, what's expected of you as a TA in a teaching position).

It may not be easy all the time to do this.  Teaching is a skill just like anything else.  Having knowledge doesn't mean having the ability to convey it effectively.

> My question is briefly, how to handle silly questions?  By silly, I mean questions that are unrelated to the material of the course.

I find it very hard to believe that a student came up to you randomly at the end of a lecture and asked you about something that is utterly unrelated to the course work.  If you teach math, I'm fairly confident a student didn't approach you asking about the digestion mechanisms of an African elephant.  Let's say you're a TA for MATH 1101 and going over basic calculus, and they ask you a question about geometry.  To *you*, who supposedly understands all of this stuff, their question may appear completely unrelated and off-topic.  But they *don't know any better*.  If the question genuinely is outside the scope of the course, explain to them *why* that's the case.  "Well, you see, quadratic formulas are actually only very loosely related to differential calculus, so your question is a bit outside of the scope of this course.  You'll learn more about that in MATH 1103."

> He got upset, and he told me: "You are paid to answer my questions!" ... I got angry [...]

It's not unreasonable to get angry when people verbally attack you or your profession, but as a teacher in any capacity, like it or not, a big part of your job is essentially *human relations*.  You aren't there to sit at a podium and rant about whatever your little heart desires.  You're there to *convey information* to people.  Human beings.  Each of whom has their own ways of learning, their own things they think are important, their own philosophies, their own lives.  It's your job to actually *connect* with them and get something you're saying into their skulls.  It's a skill of *human interaction*.  So while you're free to experience whatever emotion you want, you must always still act in a *professional manner* toward your students.  It's part of your responsibilities.  It doesn't matter if you think your student is a rotten turd; you degrade yourself, your department, and your entire institution by *treating* him that way.  Again, if you don't think you can handle dealing with people on a day-to-day basis, and thus with the inevitable conflict, go back into research or leave academia entirely.

Here's an example of how to handle conflict in a professional manner: "I'm sorry that you're frustrated.  I have another lecture to give right now, but why don't you come to my office hours or send me an e-mail so that we can discuss this further?  If I can't resolve your issue, you may have to go see Professor So-and-so, as he has more knowledge and experience than I do."

Part of the issue is that you've come here asking for advice and have given absolutely *no* detail about your problem except that a student asked you a question after a lecture which you thought was stupid.  So all anyone can do is conjecture and try to make assumptions based on their own experience.  If the goal of your question is genuinely to handle these kinds of situations effectively and to become a better teacher (and not just to rant about a student you dislike, as seems to be the case), how could you possibly expect to get a decent answer with the information you've provided?  How would *you* answer such a question?

Actually, I think we already have the answer to that; you'd just tell them:

> "You can't be serious, this is not a question!"

Comment: I downvoted this for your first paragraph, which is way out of line. Being a TA, the original poster is presumably quite young, inexperienced and at the very start of their potential academic career. So he/she was rude to a student - it's not the end of the world, and he/she has a lot of time to improve. "You should probably be nicer to your pupils" is appropriate advice, "you should probably leave academia" is idiotic.

Comment: @DanPetersen Fair enough.  I take your point.  And if you only read what the OP wrote in his question, I could see how you would reach that conclusion.  I think if you track what he's said throughout the course of the discussion, however, it becomes a bit more clear why I said that.  I'm basing the claim on many of his comments and responses to other people, not simply on the test of his question.  Maybe he really was just having a bad day, but everything he's said in this Q&A/comments has made a lasting negative impression of his people skills (which is the premise for not teaching).

Comment: I suppose I should rephrase it to say "not teach", since research is a fundamental purpose of universities as well.  Though as political as academia is, you *would* still require some people skill.

Comment: I would offer a caution about the "customer service" way of thinking: you have to be clear who the customers are (and it is not just the students nor their parents). I wrote a few words about that in a separate answer.

Comment: @dmckee Again, fair enough.  I realize that the word "customer" in academia has some odd/unpleasant connotations.  I'll change it to "human relations", because that's really what I mean.  Just the fact that you need to deal with people in a cordial, courteous, professional manner at all times.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Oh, by all means. But we have obligation that go beyond a naive construction of serving the students. We have a dual roll aiding and serving them on one hand, and gatekeeping access to education credential on another. And, as you say, always in a professional manner.

Comment: @dmckee Oh, I agree with that completely.  The whole idea that higher education is a "human right" or that you ought not have to work or have some intelligence to get a degree is nonsense and certainly not what I mean.  I understand how it could come across that way, using the word "customer", which was something the OP said in the comments below his question: "student pays, we have to treat him like he's smart; student pays, he has to get an A."  That's not the claim.  By all means, if someone doesn't meet the standards of the class or the institution, flunk them, fail them, get them out[...]

Comment: @dmckee It's just that there's no sense in *teaching* the material if you hold some great disdain for your students or are unwilling to help them combat their ignorance.  If you're simply going to tell them they're idiots when they come to you with questions, what's the point?  Knowledge for knowledge's sake is fine and has its place (e.g., why doing research is recommended), but if you really want to be part of the *educational process*, there has to be someone to *educate*.  There's no sense in teaching a class to people who already have the answers to all of their questions.

Comment: @dmckee And, yes.  There's a way to tell someone they're an idiot and flunk them from a course or expel them from a university in a professional, courteous way.  Haha.  Just because someone is a customer in a store doesn't mean you don't have security escort them out or arrest them when they go streaking through the aisles naked.  The dollar isn't almighty (or an "end-in-itself", as Kant would say).  My apologies if it came across as me saying everyone and their dog should be handed a diploma if they pay for it.  Certainly not my intention.

Comment: You may have read too much into my comments. I've been faced with the *"I'm a customer line"* once or twice, and I feel I did an adequate job diffusing the situation, but I want my fellows to be forewarned and forearmed when it comes to answering that kind of assertion. I rather enjoy teaching intro classes (though I enjoy teaching advanced classes more), but there are limits to the nonsense I'll put up with.

Answer (score 20):

> A student, recently, asked me at the end of a lab session, a very silly question. I say silly because:
>   1) it is not related to the lecture,
>   2) it is asked at the end of a lecture - and the class room was already full with the students of the next class, and
>   3) I have previously talked about this issue.

I don't see how any of these make the question "silly."

> 1) It is not related to the lecture

It might be a silly question if it was not related to the **course material** (I once had a student ask me about my favorite flavor of Jell-O, for example), but not all questions need to be related to the **lecture**. Part of teaching is synthesizing concepts. I hope you don't compartmentalize your lessons so much that you wouldn't answer a question about Lecture 3 during or after Lecture 6.

> 2) it is asked at the end of a lecture - and the class room was already full with the students of the next class

I don't see how this makes a question "silly." At worst, the timing is bad. Why not just step into the hallway and answer the question? Or, if you don't have time for that, ask the student to visit during an office hour? Or start your next lecture by answering that question?

> 3) I have previously talked about this issue.

This is one is most alarming in my mind. So, you talk about an issue, and you expect every student will understand it completely, the first time through, and never ask for it to be explained a second or third time?

I agree that students can be stubborn and selfish and have a sense of entitlement. But professors can also be arrogant and condescending and not have a very good grasp of pedagogy and andragogy.

Which is the case here? I believe that some standardized tests have an answer that goes something like, "Not enough information given." A student telling an instructor, "You are paid to answer my question!" seems like a naïve view of academia, particularly if the question isn't relevant. However, your definition of a "silly" question leaves plenty of room for the student to be making a valid point. If the question is related to the course, then you *should* answer that question – even if the room is full, and you have talked about it before.

Comment: I think it's just your definition of silly, and the TA's definition of silly are different. They need to vacate the room asap, so psychologically, maybe he was panicked and need to rush, no time to explain what have been explained before. Do you like to talk again about what you've talked? Sometimes students dont ask about further explanation, but something that has already been answered. S/he should've listen carefully, or ask a friend or study it again before asking again.

Comment: @kate - I **love** rehashing what's already been discussed; it's often a sign that the students are engaged, interested, and striving to understand the material even better. While there is nothing wrong with asking a friend, or studying harder, I wouldn't want my students thinking that they should only approach me as a last resort after those other avenues have been explored first.

Answer (score 11):

This strikes me as a poorly titled question since the key issue is not the student's behaviour but yours.

Have you ever wondered why "there are no silly questions" is such a widespread position? It's not because there are no silly questions, we know perfectly well that there are, just as we know that there are students who will ask questions they could answer themselves if they'd simply bothered to listen and some students who are thicker than too short planks.

So why say "there are no silly questions"? Because there's a much bigger problem with students who *should* ask questions not asking those questions and thus not getting the information they need than there is with students asking silly questions. By adopting and respecting the position that "there are no silly questions" you help create an environment in which students feel free to ask their questions and thus create a more positive and helpful learning environment for all.

Your student shouldn't have said that to you; but you behaved badly first and you're the one who is supposed to be a professional not them.

Comment: Let's be blunt: If "You can't be serious, this is not a question!" seems to you like a reasonable way to address a student, your communication skills need some work. Fortunately there are ways to improve. Read. Reflect. Ask others who've seen you communicate for feedback. Practice phrasing things in non confrontational ways. (Reflect on this: Why is "You can't be serious!" likely to escalate conflict rather than defuse it?)

Answer (score 8):

> “You are paid to answer my questions!”

Actually, you are paid to do something rather more subtle than that. You see, contrary to common belief, the students are not your customers. Or at least they are not your only customers.

You are paid to help students to learn *and* to evaluate that learning and certify it as acceptable *only* if it meets certain standards (which are set by the customs of your discipline and the expectations of people who will be looking at the credentials that the school does issue and are enforced by the accreditation agencies).

So answering their questions is a part of your job, but so is knowing which question are meaningful or helpful.

None of which really illuminates what you should do when confronted by this student, but it does provide a better framework for understanding your job than the one suggested by the student.

Comment: <quote>So answering their questions is a part of your job, but so is knowing which question are meaningful or helpful.</quote>  I agree with this, but am not sure that I agree with the implicit corollary:  a teacher who, having identified a question as not meaningful or helpful, then does not answer it, has not done his or her job.  I think that the appropriate next step at such a stage is to identify *why* the question was asked, and, if possible, to turn it *into* a meaningful or helpful question.

Answer (score 3):

Technically the student is wrong regarding the payment part. You are not paid to answer any question at any time. And I'd be more interested in how to handle impolite students/clients, if this is the case, than in the silliness of their questions.

However, I doubt that your account is accurate. At one place you claim that you have already dealt with the issue during the lecture and at another you claim it was not related. Besides that, you find it acceptable to post the reaction of the student, but do not find acceptable to disclose what question he asked, which would have been essential to know how to react towards it.

So:

If the question has a truly obvious answer, or if the student is truly lost, follow a Socratic approach, asking questions to make him realize how easy would have been to him to know the answer. This part is probably somehow related to your job, which is to educate people.

Comment: Why bother suggesting that the OP is being less than honest? We can still answer the question as asked even if the account is not totally accurate.

Answer (score 3):

If a question in itself makes no sense, try to think about the motivation behind the question.  Answer the question behind the question.
Just because someone is bad at phrasing a good question doesn't mean that he's not worthy of an answer.

There are however cases when you don't want to invest the time to help a particular individual at a particular time.
In that case I would simply say: "I need a moment of rest to be at my mental peak at my next lecture. If the question is important to you, come back at office hours."

In general, if you don't want to answer a question at a particular time don't say: "It is already late, but let me know about your question."

Comment: Nope Christian, I was going to answer a question if it was related to what I teaching in class during that day.

Comment: @AJed : Why? What's the goal you are try to accomplish? If you goal is to help the student learn something my first paragraph addresses it.

If your goal is to answer question about a lecture for the sake of answering question about a lecture, then get better goals.

Comment: I like your answer, and thanks. The problem, though, is that you are judging that I did not want to answer a question.

Comment: @AJed: I'm not. I don't care whether or not you want to answer the question. To the extend that I judge, I just particular reasons for not answering it.

Answer (score 3):

**never become angry in the class.**

I teach in 13 classes and this is my experiences :

1. the meaning of being angry is your mind does not work at the moment and you can not handle the situation. so better that our mind tell us what to do than our emotions.
2. by being angry we just show students our week point. and that decrees their respect to their teacher.
3. one example :

Once in one of my classes I said something and the student told me "**...that is silly work**" . For the moment all of students become quite to see what is my response . they watch me and my face to find any distortion or loosing my control. they all know he said very bad things but they just wait to see my reaction.

**WHAT I DID ?**
For the moment less than 2 second I become quite and I said "**...OK what is the next part of algorithm ...**"

other students reaction after my word :

1. they all laugh him. because with any word I told him "**Your idea is not so important which I should care about** "
2. I see the other student trust me more. I see that.